# Logstash can't (read and) store log data from a file after python write new data into it

Tags: python, elastic-stack

I used a python script to write log to a special file automatically,
which file is also the source log of my log-stash.
The context can been written correctly (by python scrpit),
but after that log-stash can't read log data any more, and can't work even restart the logstash.

The main steps are：

1. start elasticsearch（with default conf） and logstash(with conf showed bellow)
   the logstash can store all the data automatically (in the source log file) to the elasticsearch, and output the info to console.
2. start the python script(showed bellow) to write json data into the source log file.
   Data is successful been written. 
   but the logstash can't read new data any more. 
   even I restart the logstash, it still can't read data in the source log or store it to elasticsearch.

Has anyone met this problem before? 
Here is my python code:

```
 def store(filepath,data):
  with open(filepath, 'a') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json.dumps(data))
    json_file.write("\r")
    # json_file.close

def load(filepath):
  with open(filepath) as json_file:

    data = json.load(json_file)
    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":

data = {}
sourceFilePath = "elk_data_source.log"
destFilePath = "elk_data_dest2.log"
for i in range(1,20):
    data= load(sourceFilePath)
data["eventType"] = "*ABC"
    store(destFilePath, data)

read = open(destFilePath)
line=read.readline()  
while line:
print line 
    ''' 
context = json.loads(line)
context = context.join([ string.strip().rsplit("}" , 1)[0] ,  "}"] )
print context  
'''
line=read.readline()  
 # read.close 
 read.close()
```

Here is my logstash conf file,which can work correctly if manually input data  into this log:

```
input {
       file {
              type => "accounts"
              path => "/ELK_Data/elk_data_dest2.log"

              start_position => "beginning"

            }
      }

filter {

        json{
              source => "message"
            }
       }

output {
       stdout { codec=> rubydebug }
       elasticsearch {
            hosts => "localhost:9200"
            index => "logstash-2016.12.20"
                     }
      }
```

Here is my elk_data_source.log

```
  {"eventType": ["*icbc"], "prodName": ["LDAP"], "prodFmid": ["HRSL420"], "systemSmfid": ["EIMG"]}
```

versions: 
logstash-5.0.0
elasticsearch-2.4.1
Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather, source file is **elk_data_source.log** and you are trying to overwrite `"eventType" = ["*icbc"]` to `*ABC`. But what you missed is.. value of `"eventType"` is an **array** and you are writing it with a **single value** instead -- `*ABC`.

Change `data["eventType"] = "*ABC"` to  `data["eventType"] = ["*ABC"]`.

This should solve. If possible try to compare both the files with file comparison softwares. Also, do check the matching braces or additional space that might be causing issues while reading and formatting from files.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
my python script is used to modify data from  "eventType" = ["*icbc"] to *ABC. but if i didn't change anything, just paste the source file data to the  destination file， the logstash still can‘t work.

Comment: i will check "matching braces or additional space" carefully again.

Comment: The problem is still on.
The data copied by python script（not change anything just copy） can't recognized by logstash.
If i manually input the same data（just the copied data by python script） into the destination file (elk_data_dest2.log)
Then the logstash would recognize.

Comment: If you are using Windows, there is a software called winmerge, that compares files. Do use the software to compare both the log files. There are other software for file comparison for Linux and Mac.

Comment: You are writing to the file 20 different times. Consider concatenating all 20 JSON dumps to a single string and then write it at once. In any program io operations are expensive.

Comment: Just try to write 1 JSON dumps to file (not 20). Mostly the reader needs the log file to contain data in JSON format. Writing 20 of JSON data with \r between them doesn't make them JSON compatible

Comment: Dear dhistan
Thanks for you reply
I have solved it. I replace this line

    json_file.write("\r")
with
     json_file.write("\n")

Then logstash can read the change easily 

Thanks so much for all your adise
hope get more help in python  if possible in the future

Comment: @wenterjoy Glad to be of help. Tag me in future if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question completely but,
Isn't the last line supposed to be `read.close()` instead of `read.close`
also even in the first function `json_file.close()` which actually is redundant if have to use with `with`

Comment: Thanks very much. I will have a try to remove those "()" and redundant parts in "with"
PS: I am lack of Python experience

Comment: I found there are many ".close()" written without “()”  on the internet
This mislead me.

Comment: Can you rephrase your original question? I can be of more help.

Comment: Dear dhishan
I update the question
hope you can understand.

Comment: Dear dhishan
I have tried with removing the "close()" in "with" block,and add “()” to the last "close", the logstash can't work too.